# Escaping multiple characters in an ActionScript regular expression

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Are there special strings for that, such as \Q and \E in Java?
Thanks.

Comment: They should work the same. I did not down-vote but, I suggest you edit your question to show an example string + expected output. Also show your AS3 code of how you handled this regular expression. It'll become easier to see your problem that way..

Comment: @VC.One Are you sure? I think `\Q` and `\E` are special to Java, not part of RegEx.

Comment: @Aaron, my bad. I remember reading that AS3 uses same RegEX engine as JavaScript, somehow I made the [illogical] jump to assuming same for Java too..

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no equivalent to `\Q` and `\E` in AS3 RegExp. What you can do is the same thing [you would in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript): escape special characters for use within a `RegExp` pattern:

```
function escapeForRegExp(s:String):String {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&");
}

// Example:
var s:String = "Some (text) with + special [regex] chars?";
var r:RegExp = new RegExp("^" + escapeForRegExp(s), "g");

// Same as if you wrote the pattern with escaped characters:
/^Some \(text\) with \+ special \[regex\] chars\?/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no, you have to escape each characters one at a time with \
as described 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e91.html
If it is really an issue, you could imagine writing your own escaping function and using:

`new RegExp(escape("your text (using reserved characters ^^) [...]"))`

instead of the constant syntax

`/your text \(using reserved characters \^\^\) \[\.\.\.\]/`
If you don't want to escape the whole regex, just concatenate  the escaped & non-escaped parts

escape() function could be a RegExp one-liner, just prepending '\' to any reserved character