# fixing a regExp

Tags: regex

I found the regExp

```
            var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp("\(\?\<\=\\s)" + string + "(?=[\\s|\,])", "ig");
```

someone wrote it back in 2011.

I want to use it in my code in order to find the word string in a given text. It has to be a whole word.
The problem is that it finds the "string" only if it is not at the begining of the text and if it is not at the end of the text.
what can I do in order to find also the first and the last line of the text (the first word doesn't have a space before it, and the last one doesnt have a space or a punctuation after it.

Comment: I omitted the last part, and it works. I just want to understand what is in the last part, why it is needed? what's ?=

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex match entire words only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751301/regex-match-entire-words-only)

Comment: What language is this in? `?=` is a zero-width assertion that there will be a match at that point. I don't think whoever wrote the pattern understood regex too well the character class escaping is funny.

Comment: It seems \b is not working for me in actionscript.

Comment: If lookbehinds were allowed in ECMAScript, I'd suggest this `(?<!\S)string(?![^\s,])` Which is known as whitespace boundary behind and ahead (plus a comma boundary)

Comment: I don't see mentioning someone wrote the regex in 2011 has anything to do to help people understand your problem.

Comment: I have to give you a big -1 for not knowing anything about regular expressions and thereby picking the wrong answer. If you need to know why the answer is junk, just let me know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match a whole word, you need to match a word boundary at either end. ActionScript regular expressions match at the start and end of the string as a boundary as well.

```
var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp("\\b" + string + "\\b", "ig");
```

Note if `string` could contain regular expression meta characters, you should be [quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35437621/2557128) them.

Comment: works great on the first word but not on the last. I tried the \b with one slash now I now it has to be with 2 slashes.

Comment: I am very sorry, It works great also with the last word! (the reason it didnt work before wan not because of the regExp but because of another programatic problem I had in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

?= is a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It say that your text must be followed by the content of the parenthesis (so the searched text cannot be the last word).

To make your replace, you could use the following regexp:

```
(?<=(^|\s))text(?=([\s,]|$))
```

Remember to add the '\' when you'll add it to your RegExp string (take example from the RegExp you pasted in your question).

You can try it from the javascript console (it works only in Chrome, the other browser doesn't support the lookbehind):

```
"text ciao text texttext a, a".replace(/(?<=(^|\s))text(?=([\s,]|$))/ig,"x")
```

Return "x ciao x texttext x, x", as expected (texttext is not replaced because it isn't the searched word).

Comment: What can i do if i want it to be the last word too? same about the first word. I saw that in regex there is \b which is a word boundry, but it doesn't work in regExp. I am in Actionscript 3.0.

Comment: @EliCohen, I've added a regexp in my answer

Comment: I get no replacement. I tries with one slash and with 2 slashes befor the s, and it replaces nothing.